# acess denied in joomla when call through ajax

Tags: php, joomla

i have joomla ajax based modules for fetching data from db. i want to use this script for fetching data from db

```
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery("my query");
    $db->query();
    $res = $db->loadAssocList();
```

but it give me error like

```
    Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in
```

then i put this code at the top of the page

```
    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
```

to enable jFacotry and it is enabled as expected but now i can not enter this page as i recieve a message "Restricted access".

What should i do to over come this problem.

Comment: This error is due to the joomla frame works not accessible from your page

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you want to use Joomla methods in external file and call that file to get your data through ajax. If I am correct, Than I wold like to say that by default Joomla environment you can call any external file function directly to module. Also you can not use Joomla method directly for fetching the result from database without including the library files.

**Suggestion :** One thing which works for me while I am having the same problem. I have made a custom component and define the task in it, to fetch my data from database and call that task in to my module through ajax and show the result. This thing works for me.

Try to make an ajax call to any custom or existing component controller like below.

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index.php?option=com_custom&controller=custom&task=getdata",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope my suggestion will also help you to solve your problem. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this code check if constant `_JEXEC` is defined and if not, it shows "Restricted access" error. It is not loading or enabling anything.

Which version of Joomla are you using and where is you script (component / module)?

Comment: i am using joomla 3.1 and yes its enabaled as its working fine on all other pages but is problematic only on those pages that are called through ajax and my script is in modules folder

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to access a module with ajax call the proper method is follows

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
 $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

 $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

 $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";//This will only required when you pass module params through code
 $Module->params = $Params;
 echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

For [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068065/joomla-1-7-popup-extension-to-load-module-inside/15080277#15080277)

If you are trying to access it from current page you have load the frame work too like below but its not a good practise.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

For [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973693/how-to-access-joomla-protected-property/14974662#14974662)

Try to make an ajax call to any existing component controller like below.

```
jQuery.ajax ({

        type: "GET",

        url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&controller=productdetails&ajax_request=1&task=addItemToWaitlist",
//controller components controller name
//task the function inside controller.
        data: data,

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
}});
```

Comment: no i am not accessing whole module through ajax but i have module and inside that module i have ajax call for a page and that page is restricted due to that line of code i meantioned at the top.

Comment: can you paste the code for ajax call it passing through which component ?

Comment: jQuery.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_stune_cat_indians/getuser.php';?>",
                        data: "page="+page+'&str='+str,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            jQuery("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                jQuery("#container").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

Comment: In this way you are trying access a module file through ajax the file is not in the framework ie, you can't make an ajax call to a module like this

Comment: You have to make this ajax call to a component that related to this module like index.php?option=com_users&task=profile.mytask&param=1 etc

Comment: can you send me any example link as it sounds greate about the problem

Comment: check out edited answer and try with any existing component :)